# Magento2 - catalog product listing collection sort by price with dynamic price calculation

Tags: magento2, product-collection, product-sorting, price-sorting

product price is calculated dynamically based on certain conditions. while sorting with price it takes only default price not dynamically calculated price. the same issue with the price filter.

I can able to set the calculated price for product using event **catalog_block_product_list_collection** observer but not able to get products ordered by dynamic price.

```
<event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
    <observer name="product_price_change" instance="[vendor]\[module]\Observer\ProductCollectionDynamicPrice" shared="false" />
</event>
```

Observer - [vendor][module]\Observer\ProductCollectionDynamicPrice

```
<?php
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductCollectionDynamicPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * set dynamic price
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
    */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
       if ($productCollection instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
          $productCollection->load();
          $this->calculatePrice($productCollection);
       }

       return $this;
    }

    /**
     * set dynamic calculated price to product collection
     *
     * @param ProductCollection $collection
     * @return $this
    */
    public function calculatePrice($collection) {

     foreach ($collection as $key => $item) {
        $price = 100;  // here my cuustom logic to calculate dynamic price based on conditions 
        $item->setMinPrice($price);
     }

     return $collection;

   }
 }
```

If I echoing **min_price** then able to get updated **min_price** but not able to get correct product orders collection sort by price.

Please anyone can help for the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume, In Category page you are trying to sort by the price and not getting the correct order while you want your prices to be displayed as well as used in sorting.

**etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="sortby_extend_default_sort_filters" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Toolbar" sortOrder="99" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Toolbar**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Zend\Filter\Boolean;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * Product list toolbar plugin
 */
class Toolbar
{
    protected $test;
    protected $storeManagerInterface;
    protected $_flag = true;

    public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface)
    {
        $this->storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    }

    public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
                                        \Closure $proceed,
                                        $collection
    )
    {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);
        $pageSize = $collection->getPageSize();
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->clear();
        }
        if ($currentOrder && $currentOrder == 'price' && $this->_flag == false) {
            //Get current store information
            $currentStore = $subject->getCollection()->getStoreId();
            $currency = $this->storeManagerInterface ->getStore($currentStore)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

            //add you custom calculation here in the result/collection
            $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->columns(
                array(
                    'new_price' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("IF (
                    YOURCONDITION IN DB QUERY,
                    TRUE Value,
                    False Value)"))
            );
            //to reset sorting order 
            $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
            $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('`new_price` ' . $subject->getData('_current_grid_direction')));
        }
        $this->_flag = false;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

You've to add your logic using SQL Query/Operators.